# Um vetor em C, que se atualiza os valores em tempo real, de acordo com os números informados

Tags: c, array, algoritmo

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define tamanho 5

struct test {
  int vetor5;
}casa[tamanho];

//funcão para o vetor da struct
void recebe (void) {
  for (int p=0; p<tamanho; p++) {
    printf("| %d",casa[p].vetor5);
  }
}

int main (){
  //INICIALIZANDO VETOR DA STRUCT
  for (int i=0; i<tamanho; i++) {
    casa[i].vetor5=0;
  }

  recebe(); 
  for(int y=0 ; y<tamanho; y++) {
    //insiro os valores
    printf("\nInsira um novo valor para a struct:");                                                                     
    scanf("%d", &casa[y].vetor5);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não ficou claro o problema. Você quer aumentar/diminuir o tamanho do vetor dinamicamente?

Comment: O tamanho permanece, o mesmo. Seria tipo o vetor está todo com 0. Quando eu informar qualquer número, ele se atualiza em tempo real. Passando a exibir o novo número informado, juntamente com os demais.

Comment: Não sei se entendi mas não seria apenas uma questão de imprimir (via função recebe) o vetor após a atualização do vetor? Aliás recebe é um nome estranho para uma função que só imprime.

Comment: Talvez nem precise ser via função. Mas o que eu estou tentando fazer é que o vetor, permaneça em exibição enquanto informa os novos dados inseridos.

Comment: não dá para entender o que você quer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi bem, você quer mostrar o estado atual do vetor e, assim que inserir um novo valor, o terminal da um reload e já mostra o vetor com o novo valor inserido.

Se for isso, basta você passar a chamada da função `recebe();` para dentro do `for`, colocando antes da chamada uma função que limpe o terminal a cada vez que for imprimir na tela, dessa forma:

```
for(int y=0 ; y<tamanho; y++) {
  //insiro os valores
  system("cls"); //caso use windows, função que limpa a tela do terminal
  recebe();
  printf("\n\nInsira um novo valor para a struct: ");
  scanf("%d", &casa[y].vetor5);
}
```

Da forma que está a cima, o programa encerrará assim que o número de elementos forem totalmente preenchidos. Caso queira que seja infinito, deve implementar um vetor encadeado, onde o seu limite de armazenamento será a memória RAM do PC. Ou pode também colocar esse mesmo `for` que está a cima dentro de um outro laço, daí arma uma condição de parada e um jeito do contador ser zerada ao chegar no tamanho final (5).

Comment: Obrigado a todos, pessoal.